# How to break span-element inline-block over row inside container?

Tags: css, flexbox, rows

I have the following HTML code:

```
<span class="container">

    <span id="item1" class="item">
        <button class="removeitem"></button>
        <span class="text"></span>
    </span>

    <span id="item2" class="item">
        <button class="removeitem"></button>
        <span class="text"></span>
    </span>

    <span id="item3" class="item">
        <button class="removeitem"></button>
        <span class="text"></span>
    </span>

</span>
```

Imagine the `#item3` extends `.container`, but overflow is hidden. How can I achieve that the elements inside are still visible and will continue in the following row?

I tried the following (in Sass-syntax):

```
.container
    display: flex
    justify-content: flex-start
    flex-wrap: wrap
```

But `#item3` will just appear on the next row.

I tried making everything `display: inline`, but then I can not assign any `height`-properties.

I attached an image of what I want to achieve.

This is what the layout should look like. #item3 continues in the next row:
[image]

Comment: You can't break **any** element across rows. This is not possible.

Comment: What about text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is not technically possible unless you use the natural wrapping of text as in this example:

```
.item {
  display: inline;
  background: yellow;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  line-height: 2;
}
```

**Fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/658tdurx/1/